# Meaning of Responsive web design

Tags: website-design, responsive-design

Many graphics and web design companies ask for the knowledge of responsive web design. What is responsive web design actually is and what are the tools someone should know to create and design responsive web?

Comment: Have you googled this?

Comment: @DA01, Yes i have.

Comment: There's a LOT of information out there on this topic. Google will get you all sorts of information. Was there something specific you didn't understand? Perhaps this question could be reworded to be narrower in scope?

Comment: @DA01, yes, was expecting more info's about the required tools and software's which I should know good. But did not expect down voting. Some experienced persons here in stack get annoyed very fast watching some question from a novice. I think they only expect only the highly experienced persons here.

Comment: The downvotes are likely because this is an easily google-able question. We encourage novices, but we do expect a bit of effort be put into the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short list of terms you need knowledge about would be:

- Viewport settings (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)
- CSS media queries / CSS breakpoints
- Mobile First development
- Difference between adaptive and responsive design
- Scalable images (SVG) / Retina-ready images (@2x)

A nice overview for starters: http://www.fastcodesign.com/3038367/9-gifs-that-explain-responsive-design-brilliantly

Comment: Good answer, might be worth adding the key central idea that unites these technical points: that **responsive design is about creating *flexible* designs that work or adapt themselves to work across a wide range of devices** - in particular (but not exclusively) different widths and different resolutions.

Answer (score -1):

When I had the same question, I found this article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

For me it was very useful, I hope for you to be.

Comment: Hi Kevin, on StackExchange websites Answers should not be link-only. You can link to that article but need to summarize it as well otherwise people will probably downvote your Answer. If you don't want to Summarize the link then its better to just leave it as a Comment on the Question.